# How To Edit a Backbone Model and Wait For Save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'll try to describe this as succinctly as possible. Within the app I'm working on, Backbone models are saved and then they can be edited later. Currently, I have it setup where the functionality is entirely dynamic.

Example: `this.model.set('attribute', value)`

Standard stuff there. Here's the issue. The client wants the updated model not to be saved until the user explicitly clicks a save and finish button.

Previously, I was using this pattern for editing:

```
this.model = options.previousModel || new NamedBackboneModel({
    id: this.model.get('id'),
    attr: otherModel.get('attr')
});
```

I've made the properties and model names in that example generic but it worked great. Throughout the view I would use `model.set('attr' value)` and it was perfect.

What's the best way I can make edits to the previousModel without immediately saving them to the previous model?

I looked at using a vanilla object to track changes, but I'm thinking there has to be a better way that is more inline with a typical Backbone pattern.

Naturally, I tried `new NamedBackboneModel(options.previousModel.toJSON())` but because of a nested collection on the Model that didn't work as expected and would require some architectural changes.

I figured a clone on the previousModel would work but I didn't have any luck with that approach either. Thanks for any help and please let me know if I need to provide more clarification.

Comment: doing model.set('attribute',value) will not save it to the db ,  so you can always revert back the old model by doing a collection fetch if user decides not to save ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of methods to make this work. I added store and revert functions to the model like so:

```
store: function() {
    this._storedAttributes = _.clone(this.attributes);
    this._storedCollection = _.clone(this.collection().toJSON());
},

revert: function() {
    if (this._storedAttributes) {
        this.set(this._storedAttributes, {
            silent: true
        });
        this.collection.remove(this.collection.models, { silent: true });
        this.collection.reset(this._storedCollection, { silent: true });

        // For syncing local storage up the chain
        if(!this.isNew()) { this.trigger('change'); }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass `{silent: true}` when you call `model.set()`.

Then you can retrieve a list of previous values by calling `model.previousAttributes()` to get all previous attributes. or `model.previous("name")` to get specific attribute.

When you want to discard the previous attributes, you can call `model.change()` to invoke 'change' event.

When you want to save, you can `model.save({silent:false})` which will save and discard previous attributes, or passing `{silent:true}` will keep previous changes.

Comment: This would work for most situations but with the nested collection it is self-contained as its own object. That's the challenge I'm dealing with here. I'm working save a copy of it as well and I'll restore everything in the view.remove() function. Thanks for your contribution.